# Error "ldap_sasl_bind_s failed" on n-way multi-master openldap

Tags: openldap, slapd

I am trying to connect openldap nodes in cluster but I receive the
   following message (The password is update on all different openldap).

What password is failing and how can I force to be update?

```
Feb 25 18:57:01 ldap03 slapd[9556]: slapd starting
Feb 25 18:57:01 ldap03 slapd[9556]: slap_client_connect: URI=ldap://ldap01 DN="cn=admin,dc=clients,dc=enterprise,dc=com" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (-1)
Feb 25 18:57:01 ldap03 slapd[9556]: do_syncrepl: rid=001 rc -1 retrying (4 retries left)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I am met same issue...

```
625cf83c slapd starting
625cf83c slap_client_connect: URI=ldaps://ldap.example.com:636 DN="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (-1)
625cf83c do_syncrepl: rid=123 rc -1 retrying
```

But in my case, the issue was on transport layer. The OpenLDAP server was built without SSL support. Re-installation the OpenLDAP server with SSL support solved my issue.